# Is it possible to write the Coulomb Hamiltonian in terms of creation and annihilation operators similar to harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Is it possible to write the Coulomb Hamiltonian in terms of creation and annihilation operators similar to the harmonic oscillator so that we can have the same commutations relations similar to that of the harmonic oscillator?

Comment: found it here http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Fall_2015/9_10_2015.pdf  at  1.3.4 , searching for "the Coulomb Hamiltonian in terms of creation and annihilation operators"

Comment: Thanks a lot! anna v and DanielC